# Incorrect Checksum Errors All Over Program

Tags: c++, memory, malloc

I've written a program that times a depth-first search for two implementations of a graph, an adjacency list and an adjacency matrix. However, my program is consistently crashing with the following line:

HPCHW2(1532,0x7fff727c6310) malloc: *** error for object 0x1002000c8: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.

The two hexadecimal numbers are the same on different runs. However, this crash happens at different lines on different runs, and I'm not allocating any heap memory myself in this program. The program always makes it past the first outer for loop in main, but then crashes somewhere in the `AdjacencyMatrixGraph` code in the second iteration. Most of the crashes have been in the method `connected`, but have been at different lines and different variables, sometimes crashing when I'm pushing onto `stack`, and sometimes when I'm defining the variable `discovered`. The program also crashed once in the constructor for `AdjacencyMatrixGraph`.

What causes this error if I'm not allocating any memory myself? I'm assuming that any under the hood allocation shouldn't normally be modifying freed memory. Also, how would I go about debugging this error?

This is C++11 and I'm on Mac OS Mavericks.

Here's my code for reference:

AdjacencyList.cpp

```
#include "AdjacencyListGraph.h"

#include <cstdlib>

using std::list;

AdjacencyListGraph::AdjacencyListGraph(int size) :
    adjacencyList(vector<vector<int>>(size)),
    _size(size) {

}

void AdjacencyListGraph::addEdge(int begin, int end) {

    adjacencyList[begin].push_back(end);
    adjacencyList[end].push_back(begin);
}

int AdjacencyListGraph::size() {

    return _size;
}

bool AdjacencyListGraph::connected(int begin, int end) {


    // stack to track vertices to process
    list<int> stack = list<int>();
    stack.push_front(begin);

    // value of discovered[i] is whether vertex i has been discovered
    vector<bool> discovered = vector<bool>(size(), false);

    while (!stack.empty()) {

        // process top vertex
        int curr = stack.front();
        stack.pop_front();

        if (!discovered[curr]) {

            discovered[curr] = true;

            vector<int>& neighbors = adjacencyList[curr];

            // examine neighbors
            for (size_t i = 0; i < neighbors.size(); ++i) {

                int neighbor = neighbors[i];

                // done
                if (neighbor == end) {
                    return true;
                }

                // else process later
                stack.push_front(neighbor);
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

AdjacencyMatrixGraph.cpp

```
#include "AdjacencyMatrixGraph.h"

using std::list;

AdjacencyMatrixGraph::AdjacencyMatrixGraph(int size) :
    adjacencyMatrix(vector<bool>(size * size, false)),
    _size(size) {
    // has crashed here once
}

void AdjacencyMatrixGraph::addEdge(int begin, int end) {

    if (begin == end) {
        return;
    }

    adjacencyMatrix[begin * size() + end] = true;
    adjacencyMatrix[end * size() + begin] = true;
}

int AdjacencyMatrixGraph::size() {

    return _size;
}

bool AdjacencyMatrixGraph::connected(int begin, int end) {

    // stack to track vertices to process
    list<int> stack = list<int>();
    stack.push_front(begin); // sometimes crashes here 

    // value of discovered[i] is whether vertex i has been discovered
    vector<bool> discovered = vector<bool>(size(), false); // sometimes crashes here

    while (!stack.empty()) {

        // process top vertex
        int curr = stack.front();
        stack.pop_front();

        if (!discovered[curr]) {

            discovered[curr] = true;

            // examine neighbors
            for (int i = 0; i < size(); ++i) {

                // no edge between curr and i
                if (!adjacencyMatrix[curr * size() + i]) {
                    continue;
                }

                // done
                if (i == end) {
                    return true;
                }

                // else process later
                stack.push_front(i); // sometimes crashes here
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <chrono>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>

#include "AdjacencyListGraph.h"
#include "AdjacencyMatrixGraph.h"

using std::vector;
using std::set;
using std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
using std::chrono::duration;
using std::chrono::duration_cast;
using std::mt19937;

void clearCache() {

    const vector<int> intsToSum = vector<int>(1e9, 1);
    volatile long long sum = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < intsToSum.size(); ++i) {
        sum += intsToSum[i];
    }
}

bool randomBool() {

    const double seed = high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
    mt19937 mt_rand(seed);

    return bool(mt_rand() % 2);
}

vector<bool> randomAdjacencyMatrix(int size) {

    vector<bool> adjacencyMatrix = vector<bool>(size);

    for (int i = 0; i < size * size; ++i) {
        adjacencyMatrix[i] = randomBool();
    }

    return adjacencyMatrix;
}





int main() {

    const vector<int> sizes = {20, 50, 100, 200};

    const int numRepeats = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < sizes.size(); ++i) {

        int size = sizes[i];

        printf("size: %d\n", size);


        /* Initialize function-wide variables */


        vector<bool> adjacencyMatrix = randomAdjacencyMatrix(size);

        high_resolution_clock::time_point start;
        high_resolution_clock::time_point stop;


        /* Initialize adjacency matrix */


        AdjacencyMatrixGraph adjacencyMatrixGraph = AdjacencyMatrixGraph(size);

        for (int row = 0; row < size; ++row) {
            for (int col = 0; col < size; ++col) {

                if (adjacencyMatrix[row * size + col]) {
                    adjacencyMatrixGraph.addEdge(row, col);
                }
            }
        }


        /* Time 1 */


        double time1Elapsed = 0;
        volatile int count = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < numRepeats; ++j) {

            clearCache();

            start = high_resolution_clock::now();

            for (int begin = 0; begin < size; ++begin) {
                for (int end = 0; end < size; ++end) {
                    if (adjacencyMatrixGraph.connected(begin, end)) {
                        ++count;
                    }
                }
            }

            stop = high_resolution_clock::now();

            time1Elapsed += duration_cast<duration<double>>(stop - start).count();
        }

        printf("    time1 -- average time: %f\n", time1Elapsed / numRepeats);


        /* Initialize adjacency list */


        AdjacencyListGraph adjacencyListGraph = AdjacencyListGraph(size);

        for (int row = 0; row < size; ++row) {
            for (int col = 0; col < size; ++col) {

                if (adjacencyMatrix[row * size + col]) {
                    adjacencyListGraph.addEdge(row, col);
                }
            }
        }


        /* Time 2 */


        double time2Elapsed = 0;
        count = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < numRepeats; ++j) {

            clearCache();

            start = high_resolution_clock::now();

            for (int begin = 0; begin < size; ++begin) {
                for (int end = 0; end < size; ++end) {
                    if (adjacencyListGraph.connected(begin, end)) {
                        ++count;
                    }
                }
            }

            stop = high_resolution_clock::now();

            time2Elapsed += duration_cast<duration<double>>(stop - start).count();
        }

        printf("    time2 -- average time: %f\n\n", time2Elapsed / numRepeats);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Edit: Figured it out, silly mistake, I was allocating way less space than needed for a vector but the program was happy to read hundreds of values before crashing.

Comment: Simplify as much as you can. Turn off the randomness and hard code some values. Pare it down to the *simplest* code and the *smallest* graph that produce the error. Once that's done, if you don't see the problem, post the [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Not related to your error but in a few places you do `list<int> stack = list<int>();`. You can just do `list<int> stack;` to default construct an empty `std::list`. Not sure where you learned that `= list<int>()` pattern but it's completely pointless.

Comment: @Blastfurnace Whoops, too used to working with pointers, thanks.

Comment: for vectors you can replace `[idx]` by the bounds-checked `at(idx)` and any problems will be shown as exception with linenumber.

Answer (score 0):

> What causes this error if I'm not allocating any memory myself?

`std::vector` et al do allocate memory on your behalf. If you misused them, you can easily get errors similar to what you're experiencing.

If I had to guess, I'd say that you have an out-of-bounds access somewhere in your code (bear in mind that operators like `std::vector`'s `[]` do not validate the index you're trying to access).

If you can't find the error by examining the code, it might be worth giving [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) a go.